Align elements left and right in the same row
In my WPF application using code-behind I am creating some cards using a Border to which I add several elements and I am trying to make the first line have text aligned to the left and a button aligned to the right, this is the result I am looking for:
desired result
But I can't do it in any way, I have tried other approaches using Grids or DockPanels but I have not been able to align the button correctly to the right either. This is the result I get:
obtained result
Este el código que estoy usando:
Border border = new Border
{
    Width = 290,
    Height = 130,
    Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0),
    CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5),
    BorderThickness = new System.Windows.Thickness(1),
    BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent,
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 47, 48, 48)),
    Tag = a.Id
};
border.MouseLeftButtonUp += MyBorder_MouseLeftButtonUp;

StackPanel stackPanelV = new StackPanel
{
    Orientation = Orientation.Vertical
};

StackPanel stackPanelL1 = new StackPanel
{
    Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
};

TextBlock textBlockL1 = new TextBlock
{
    Text = "Text line 1",
    Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(12, 10, 0, 0),
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
    FontSize = 16
};
ToggleSwitch toggle = new ToggleSwitch
{
    IsOn = true,
    Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0),
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
    OnContent = null,
    OffContent = null
};
toggle.Toggled += TsActivo_Toggled;

stackPanelL1.Children.Add(textBlockL1);
stackPanelL1.Children.Add(toggle);

TextBlock textBlockL2 = new TextBlock
{
    Text = "Text line 2",
    Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(12, 0, 0, 0),
    FontSize = 12,
    Foreground = Brushes.LightGray
};

TextBlock textBlockL3 = new TextBlock
{
    Text = "Text line 3",
    Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(12, 5, 0, 0),
    FontSize = 12,
    Foreground = Brushes.LightGray
};

TextBlock textBlockL4 = new TextBlock
{
    Text = "Text line 4",
    Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(12, 5, 0, 0),
    FontSize = 12,
    Foreground = Brushes.LightGray
};

stackPanelV.Children.Add(stackPanelL1);
stackPanelV.Children.Add(textBlockL2);
stackPanelV.Children.Add(textBlockL3);
stackPanelV.Children.Add(textBlockL4);

border.Child = stackPanelV;
contenedorFichas.Children.Add(border);

Thank you very much for the help

Replace stackPanelL1 by a Grid or DockPanel.

StackPanel is not suitable to lay out elements filling available space.

Replace the StackPanel with an Grid. as emoacht said in a comment, StackPanels are not suitable to lay out elements filling available space.
